# Can we simplify this? $x \sin(x)+\cos(x)+c$ where c is just a constant!

Tags: trigonometry

Can we simplify this? $$x \sin(x)+\cos(x)+c,\; \text{ where $c$ is a constant}$$

I found that formula when i integrated the integral of $x \,\cos(x)$ with respect to x.

Thank you.

Comment: You could try $\frac{e^{xi}-e^{-xi}}{2i}=\sin x$, $\frac{e^{xi}+e^{-xi}}{2}=\cos x$, but I only see that getting really ugly

Comment: It's about as simple as it gets. Worth noting is $f(x) = f(-x)$ i.e. the function is even...

Comment: No   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Answer (score 0):

> Can we simplify this?

No. We can't.

> Thank you.

You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want something different, you can note that $1^2+x^2=\left(\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)^2$ and write $$x\sin(x)+\cos(x)=\sqrt{1+x^2}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\sin(x)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\cos(x)\right)\\=\sqrt{1+x^2}\left(\cos\left(\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)\right)\sin(x)+\sin\left(\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)\right)\cos(x)\right)\\=\color{Red}{\sqrt{1+x^2}\sin\left(x+\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)\right)}.$$

I can hardly call this simpler, though.